# a large dataset to test apache ignite?

Tags: ignite

I am new to Apache Ignite. Can you please suggest a way to get a large data set (preferably CSVs along with DDL statements that is Ignite compliant), which I could use it to create schema, tables in Ignite (uses native persistence), to test a few use cases that I have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Web Console](https://console.gridgain.com/) to copy data from relational DB into Apache Ignite, creating data structure and project files along the way.

Apply it on existing database or something like [MySQL Employees sample database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/).

Web Console will connect to existing internally deployed Database using 'agent' program ran locally.

Comment: Thanks. I have web console running successfully. I have ignite cluster running. I now setup mysql and setup the sample database. Can you please point to a doc that shows how one could use web-console to copy database from mysql to ignite (native persistence)?

Comment: trying configure-> advanced -> model now. Sorry for not doing the due diligence.